Excel VBA Unlocking cells to run a macro on a different sheet then locking again
I have a macro that runs after someone fills in a form and clicks submit.  It's on the first tab of an excel spreadsheet.  It is then filling in the next available line on a worksheet that is indicated in the code.  Problem is I want to be able to protect some of the cells it is writing into, but the only way I can figure out how to do that is write in to unprotect and then reprotect the sheet when the submit button is clicked.  Unfortunately, try as I might, I'm not entirely sure where to put the coding for this and was hoping that it would be simple enough, but everything I try is coming up with an error.
Here is the original code - any ideas where in this code I could put the unprotect, run code, then reprotect all within the same VBA?
Sub Submit_Details()
        Dim shDrug As Worksheet
        Dim shLogging As Worksheet
        Dim iCurrentRow As Integer
        Dim sDrugName As String
    
        Set shLogging = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Logging")
        sDrugName = shLogging.Range("k7").Value
        Set shDrug = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sDrugName)
        iCurrentRow = shDrug.Range("A" & Application.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        If MsgBox("Is this a PA?" & vbNewLine & "If a Charging issue, click 'No'", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, confirmation) <> vbNo Then
    
        With shDrug
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 1) = Format([now()], "DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 2) = shLogging.Range("G9")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 3) = shLogging.Range("G10")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 4) = shLogging.Range("G11")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 5) = shLogging.Range("G12")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 6) = shLogging.Range("G13")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 8) = shLogging.Range("G14")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 10) = shLogging.Range("G15")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 11) = shLogging.Range("G16")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 12) = shLogging.Range("G18")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 17) = Format("Yes")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 18) = shLogging.Range("G17")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 19) = Format("--")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 20) = Format("Pending")
      
        End With
    
        shLogging.Range("G9:G18").Value = ""
    
        MsgBox "Please call Patient/Family about status!" & vbNewLine & "Data submitted successfully!"
    
        ElseIf MsgBox("Did you send back to the Clinic for processing?", vbYesNo, confirmation) <> vbNo Then
        
        With shDrug
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 1) = Format([now()], "DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 2) = shLogging.Range("G9")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 3) = shLogging.Range("G10")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 4) = shLogging.Range("G11")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 5) = shLogging.Range("G12")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 6) = shLogging.Range("G13")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 8) = shLogging.Range("G14")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 10) = shLogging.Range("G15")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 11) = shLogging.Range("G16")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 12) = shLogging.Range("G18")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 17) = Format("No")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 18) = Format("--")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 19) = Format("Yes")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 20) = Format("--")
         End With
    
        shLogging.Range("G9:G18").Value = ""
    
        MsgBox "Thank you!" & vbNewLine & "Please continue processing PA's"
    
        ElseIf MsgBox("Please send back to the Clinic for processing!", vbOKOnly, confirmation) Then
        
        With shDrug
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 1) = Format([now()], "DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 2) = shLogging.Range("G9")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 3) = shLogging.Range("G10")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 4) = shLogging.Range("G11")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 5) = shLogging.Range("G12")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 6) = shLogging.Range("G13")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 8) = shLogging.Range("G14")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 10) = shLogging.Range("G15")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 11) = shLogging.Range("G16")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 12) = shLogging.Range("G18")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 17) = Format("No")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 18) = Format("--")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 19) = Format("No")
            .Cells(iCurrentRow, 20) = Format("--")
        End With
    
        shLogging.Range("G9:G18").Value = ""
    
        MsgBox "Thank you!" & vbNewLine & "Please continue processing PA's"
        
   
    End If

End Sub

Putting in Worksheet.Unprotect and Worksheet.Protect functions.

Just don't lock it with a password. That was you can unprotect and reprotect easily, and instead focus your efforts on validating the data later. Password or not, most users won't try to hack and the ones that might are more likely to also find your password within the code.

I'm ok with not locking with a password, but the issue is I don't know where to build in the VBA to lock/unlock and have the remaining pieces work as they need. Suggestions?

Record a macro that protects, record a separate macro that unprotects, then write a fourth sub similar tzo
Sub DoTheThings()
  Call NameOfUnprotectSub()
  On Error Resume Next
  Call Submit_Details()
  Call NameOfReprotectSub()
End Sub

The On Error Resume Next is there so that, if there's an issue, setting protection back again is attempted anyway.
Once you've got that working you can try to make it better...

Maybe replacing the unprotect and reprotect subroutines with a single subroutine that takes a true/false argument so the same code both endless and disables protection.
Maybe replacing On Error Resume Next with error handling that still reprotects but also tells the user there was an error.

But that's outside of the scope of your question, and even ugly working code is better than unfinished elegant code.
